# How select rows with same values from table for some rows?

Tags: mysql

Table structure and value are given below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_sub` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_obj` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `id_sub`, `id_obj`) VALUES
  ('1','1', '1'),
  ('2','1', '2'),
  ('3','1', '3'),
  ('4','1', '10'),
  ('5','1', '1'),
  ('6','1', '10'),
  ('7','1', '3'),
  ('8','1', '10'),
  ('9','1', '1'),
  ('10','2', '30'),
  ('11','2', '10'),
  ('12','2', '1'),
  ('13','2', '10'),
  ('14','4', '1'),
  ('15','5', '1'),
  ('16','6', '1'),
  ('17','7', '1'),
  ('18','7', '10'),
  ('19','7', '11');
```

Next query select rows where I know `id_sub` and `id_obj` have same values:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM docs
WHERE `id_sub` IN (1,2,7)
AND `id_obj` IN (SELECT `id_obj` FROM `docs` GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(*)>1)
```

results:

```
   id  |  id_sub  |  id_obj
   1   |    1     |  1
   3   |    1     |  3
   4   |    1     |  10
   5   |    1     |  1
   6   |    1     |  10
   7   |    1     |  3
   8   |    1     |  10
   9   |    1     |  1
   11  |    2     |  10
   12  |    2     |  1
   13  |    2     |  10
   17  |    7     |  1
   18  |    7     |  10
```

But I can not select rows where I know `id_sub` where **all** `id_obj` have same values, ie I can not get next result:

```
   id  |  id_sub  |  id_obj
   1   |    1     |  1
   4   |    1     |  10
   11  |    2     |  10
   12  |    2     |  1
   17  |    7     |  1
   18  |    7     |  10
```

Table have ~ 20k rows, count values for `IN()` can be different.

Any ideas?

---

**UPD** - description conditions

i know values for condition `id_sub` - 1,2 or 7 (example)

i do not know values `id_obj`

conditions for expected result:

1. values `id_sub` 1, 2 or 7
2. rows do not have dublicated values `id_sub`&`id_sub`, ie rows with `id` = 1 and `id` = 5 is dublicate(see values rows) and result can be has only one row with `id` = 1 (if rows duplicated need return first duplicate row)
3. `id_obj` values should be have in each row result, ie:
   now in result i have:

   id  |  id_sub  |  id_obj

   1   |    1     |  1

   2   |    1     |  2

   3   |    1     |  3

as we can see in this rows only row with `id`= 1 has `id_obj` value which have in other rows:

```
id  |  id_sub  |  id_obj
1   |    1     |  1
12  |    2     |  1
17  |    7     |  1
```

And for all table i would like get next result:

[image]

[Sql fiddle table with rows](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ccJP9PsKRnCvaGuYmbUaWd/2)

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I don’t understand the question

Comment: I don't understand the question either.

Comment: You appear to be trying to get the first id for each distinct id_sub block, id_obj. But I don't understand why 3,1,3 is not in the result set.

Comment: Where id_sub, id_obj count > 1

Comment: @Strawberry i update question and add more description, see please

Answer (score 2):

I found a running query here.

```
SELECT MIN(a.id) AS id, a.id_sub, a.id_obj
FROM docs a
     JOIN (
        SELECT id_obj
        FROM docs
        WHERE id_sub IN (1,2,7)
        GROUP BY id_obj
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_sub) = 3
      ) b
      ON a.id_obj = b.id_obj
WHERE id_sub IN (1,2,7)
GROUP BY a.id_sub, a.id_obj
```

But I am not sure is this the best solution.
Too many subquery I guest. But better than nothing.
Hope this help.

Comment: i edit result (bad version), can you see again ? i remove duplicate rows

Comment: yes, it work, thanks you. *But I am not sure is this the best solution.* - perhaps, but now it only decision...

Answer (score 0):

To get the result I think you want your source data would have to be

```
drop table if exists docs;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_sub` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_obj` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `id_sub`, `id_obj`) VALUES
  ('1','1', '1'),
  ('2','1', '2'),
  ('3','1', '3'),
  ('4','1', '10'),
  ('5','1', '1'),
  ('6','1', '10'),
  ('7','1', '3'),
  ('8','1', '10'),
  ('9','1', '1'),
  ('10','2', '30'),
  ('11','2', '10'),
  ('12','2', '1'),
  ('13','2', '10'), (20,2,'1'),
  ('14','4', '1'),
  ('15','5', '1'),
  ('16','6', '1'),
  ('17','7', '1'), (21,7,1),
  ('18','7', '10'), (22,7,10),
  ('19','7', '11');
```

And the code to produce the expected result

```
select  min(id) id ,id_sub,id_obj
from docs
#where id_sub = 1
group by id_sub,id_obj
having count(*)  > 1
;

+------+--------+--------+
| id   | id_sub | id_obj |
+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |      1 |
|    3 |      1 |      3 |
|    4 |      1 |     10 |
|   12 |      2 |      1 |
|   11 |      2 |     10 |
|   17 |      7 |      1 |
|   18 |      7 |     10 |
+------+--------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: the result should not contain row with id=3

Comment: Why should it not? There are 2 occurances of 1,3 in the data.

Comment: because `id_sub =2` and `id_sub =7` do not have `id_obj=3`. please see [image with expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UfUr.png) in question

Comment: In that case why does id_obj = 10 appear 10 does not appear in id sub = 4,5,6?

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re simply after this... but I may have misunderstood ...

```
select a.*
  from docs a
  join (
       SELECT id_obj
         FROM docs
        WHERE `id_sub` IN (1,2,7)
        group 
           by id_obj
       having count (distinct id_sub) = 3
       ) b
 on b.id_obj = a.id _obj;
```

Comment: i have error *Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_obj' at line 5*. Check your query [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ccJP9PsKRnCvaGuYmbUaWd/2) please